# Can we use negative temperature for nuclear fusion?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, nuclear-physics, fusion

I have read in books and articles saying negative temperatures are higher than any possible positive temperature. So this temperature would also be greater than 100 million C. Can't we use it for nuclear fusion then?

Comment: Actually it's the temperature needed for fusion in an hydrogen bomb.

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas Thermonuclear fusion would require a temperature of 100 million K if I remember correctly. That is in no way the same as infinite temperature.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know what negative temperature is.

Comment: do you have a source which claims a maximum possible thermal energy temperature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thermodynamic definition of temperature is based on the way that the entropy of a system changes as we increase the energy. We expect that as we increase the energy of a system it will become more disordered and its entropy will increase, and this corresponds to the usual positive temperatures that we measure with a thermometer.

However there are systems where the entropy has a maximum value, and as we keep increasing the energy the entropy passes through a maximum and starts decreasing again. When the entropy is decreasing with increasing energy this corresponds to a negative temperature.

This is why we say negative temperatures are higher energy than positive temperatures, though the way you sometimes see this stated in popular science articles can be misleading. The energy of a system increases smoothly as we heat it, and the negative temperature is just telling us about how the disorder in the system is changing as we heat it.

It is certainly true that in the case of fusion we want as much energy as possible in our fusing gas, so we heat it as much as we can. However a hot gas is not one of the systems where the entropy can decrease with increasing energy so it won't develop a negative temperature as we heat it.

Comment: It might be helpful to add a note addressing how the negative temperature has a higher internal energy than positive temperatures *of the same system identically constrained*, not positive temperatures in general.

Comment: @gs I'm guessing that the OP is asking for an answer at a popular science level. There are already lots of questions about negative temperature on this site that go into the detail. A quick search for *negative temperature* returns lots of hits.

Answer (score 0):

Negative temperatures are possible only in systems that can saturate in entropy. An atom or a nucleus has a theoretically infinite number of high energy states and hence should never be able to achieve negative temperature.

My knowledge on this topic is limited and I would love to see what others have to say about this as well.